# How to add a data-x attribute (or custom class name) to the Cascader option list in antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is the only way to somehow watch the DOM for changes and add it using plain JS in some clever hack? If so, how would that look? I tried setting `className` and `popupClassName` but they don't cover where the `<div>` is located at the base of the DOM tree. This is what the DOM looks like for it.

[image]

Ideally I could add a custom `data-something="something"` attribute on each menu item, but the `Option` type only allows for a few props and no class name. Second best option is to add a `data-something` attribute at the popup/menu level, then I can just scope it to the options using nested selectors. Third best option is to add a custom class name somewhere in the tree, but I can't find any way to do this so far. Any help would be appreciated.